# Access mobile camera from HTML/Angular application

Tags: angular, html, camera, android-camera

I am looking to access mobile back camera from an application I am building on html5/angular. I used 
`<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />` but it always opens the front camera rather then back camera, is there any way to open back camera always?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should be able to select between the front and rear camera using the capture attribute.

For the rear camera:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="environment">
```

For the front camera, you should be able to use: `capture="user"` or just capture.

You can read a bit more about it here if you'd like: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/capturing-images/

Comment: Not working.... I am socked, actually this is same answer in many other answers. but dont know not working....

Comment: There are situations which i encountered, if camera is having multiple cameras (ex: samsung note with 4 cameras where 2 rear and 2 back cameras), in this case the expected results are not coming.
we need to switch cameras and toggle to front cam.

Answer (score 2):

There is also `ngx-webcam` with nice features:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-webcam