# How to open camera automatically on click. Angular2+

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am looking for some advice on how to open a camera on a button click. Currently, when I go to click my button it will have some options and you can just upload directly from your phone's files or take a picture and it will upload that way. That's great and all but I want my button to automatically open the camera and then you take your picture and you're done. Any suggestions on a library or some Angular2+ method that can accomplish this?

Comment: prob duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50869083/access-mobile-camera-from-html-angular-application/50869150

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to check if the user has a camera and microphone and if the permissions have been granted with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047056/is-it-possible-to-check-if-the-user-has-a-camera-and-microphone-and-if-the-permi)